# “Unauthenticated” when consuming own API with passport?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-passport

I have installed passport as the documentation instructed and added this line the '**web**' middleware:

```
'web' => [
    // Other middleware...
    \Laravel\Passport\Http\Middleware\CreateFreshApiToken::class,
],
```

and now , Iam trying to get some data using datatable ( datatables.net ) with ajax:

api.php

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'v1', 'middleware' => 'auth:api'], function()
{
  Route::get('/itemsData', 'DataController@getItemsData')->name('api.getItemsData');

});
```

in blade:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#Table').DataTable({
            "order": [],
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "ajax": "{{ route('api.getItemsData') }}",
            "columns": [{
                "data": "name"
            }, {
                "data": "created_at"
            }],
        });
    });
</script>
```

but Iam getting this as a response:

```
{"message":"Unauthenticated."}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, Passport was looking for '**X-CSRF-TOKEN**' which is **not in the request header**, so It must be added..
so, for this case:

```
 "ajax": {
     "url": "{{ route('api.getItemsData') }}",
     'beforeSend': function (request) {
             request.setRequestHeader("X-CSRF-TOKEN", '{{ csrf_token() }}');
     }
 },
```

Comment: Hallelujah :D Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the `access_token` that you have obtained from Passport in request header as

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + 'your access token'
    }
});
```